# Breadwinners by class

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics

I have a hypothesis that single-income families greatly increase as you get into the mid to upper middle class bracket. And that 2+ income sources are common in lower classes and also the extremely rich.

I can't verify this though because I can't find any research that looks into how many single income households there are by class. Instead, I see mostly gender connections.

Does anyone know of any research that could be helpful here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the third row in this table from the [American Enterprise Institute](https://www.aei.org/carpe-diem/explaining-us-income-inequality-by-household-demographics-2018-update/) (they credit the Census Bureau but I could not find the same indicators in their data)

[image]

your hypothesis is incorrect: the Mean Number of Earners per Household is increasing in income for each Quintile.

I am surprised by the average number of earners in the highest quintile, but I think it is not very surprising that the poorest people are poor because they have trouble finding stable employment.